# Is it possible to concat a string field after group by in Hive

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh

I am evaluating Hive and need to do some string field concatenation after group by. I found a function named "concat_ws" but it looks like I have to explicitly list all the values to be concatenated. I am wondering if I can do something like this with concat_ws in Hive. Here is an example. So I have a table named "my_table" and it has two fields named country and city. I want to have only one record per country and each record will have two fields - country and cities:

```
select country, concat_ws(city, "|") as cities
from my_table
group by country
```

Is this possible in Hive? I am using Hive 0.11 from CDH5 right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In database management an aggregate function is a function where the values of multiple rows are grouped together as input on certain criteria to form a single value of more significant meaning or measurement such as a set, a bag or a list.

Source: [Aggregate function - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function)

Hive's out-of-the-box *aggregate functions* listed on the following web-page:
[Built-in Aggregate Functions (UDAF - user defined aggregation function)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF))

So, **the only built-in option** (for Hive 0.11; for Hive 0.13 and above you have `collect_list`) is:
**`array collect_set(col)`**

This one will answer your request in case there is no duplicate `city` records per `country` (returns a set of objects with duplicate elements eliminated). Otherwise create your own UDAF or aggregate outside of Hive.

References for writing UDAF:

- [Writing GenericUDAFs: A Tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GenericUDAFCaseStudy)
- [HivePlugins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins)
- [Create/Drop Function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/DropFunction)